# Host mode files separately from Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor

I want to bundle ACE Editor with the desktop application and render it inside WebView. Ace is running from `file:///` protocol. Is there any way to host Mode files separately from `ace.js`? For example `ace.js` will be located inside the application bundle `/Application/MyApp.app/...`, but mode files at `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/ace/modes`.

I started with test project and have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
                + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),
        paths: {
            "ace/mode": "/Users/user/ace-build",
        }
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ace/ace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["ace/ace"], function(ace){
        var editor = ace.edit("editor-container");
        editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    });
</script>
```

I expect that module `ace/mode/javascript` will be loaded from `/Users/user/ace-build/javascript` but it loads from `ace/mode-javascript.js`. How to make modes loading from different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
require("ace/config").set("modePath", require.toUrl("ace/mode"))
```

if `ext-*` and other files are in the same folder you can do `.set("basePath", ..)` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. The only thing is in my case it was top-level require call, so I have to use async version. The final code is this http://pastebin.com/eKw2dC1i