# Attach a local mode to Ace Editor from CDN

Tags: ace-editor

If I load Ace Editor from a CDN:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ace.js

Is it possible to download a mode from another location:
http://hello.processing.org/js/vendor/ace/mode-processing.js

**Suppose I download the mode in the second link above. Can I then load it into Ace Editor on my site even though Ace is connected via CDN? How can I 
attach this custom mode?**

I've tried the following related answers with no luck:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17509307/1161948
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216371/1161948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file you are showing is not a theme it's a mode. You can use it by adding the script element to that file yourself, or use `ace.config.setModuleUrl` method tell ace which url to use when downloading `"ace/mode/processing"`

```html
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.3/ace.js></script>

<div id=editor></div>
<style >
  #editor {position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0}
</style>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("editor")
  ace.config.setModuleUrl("ace/mode/processing", "http://hello.processing.org/js/vendor/ace/mode-processing.js")
  editor.setOption("mode", "ace/mode/processing")
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like cross-site scripting and in fact the browser blocked it. So, I download the file and I put it in a local folder "ace/mode/mode-processing.js", then I rewrite that line `ace.config.setModuleUrl("ace/mode/processing", "/ace/mode/mode-processing.js");` and it should work? It's topugh for me to evaluate if it's doing anything at all - seems like the regular Java mode is better.

Comment: When you say add the script element, how do you mean exactly? Like this... `<script src="http://hello.processing.org/js/vendor/ace/mode-processing.js></script>`? In that case, what do I have to change in the code to use it from there?

Comment: same as above, but without ace.config.setModuleUrl call